# Django Distinct and Foreign Key filtering Query

Tags: django, django-views, django-orm

I found questions about this problem but no working answer, so any help is appreciated :)

I want to display a list of the lastest Record made by each Client.
Records is a model, which has Client as a field.
Client is a ForeignKey for User.

For example

```
#Initially:

Client3 --- Record6
Client2 --- Record5
Client2 --- Record4
Client1 --- Record3
Client1 --- Record2
Client1 --- Record1

#Wanted: we only keep one Record per Client, the lastest one.

Client3 --- Record6
Client2 --- Record5
Client1 --- Record3
```

This is what I have tried:

```
def LastRecordPerClient(request):
    id_list = Record.objects.order_by('-date').values_list('client__id').distinct()
    records = Record.objects.filter(id__in=id_list)
    return (request, 'records/record_list.html', {"records": records})
```

This is what I get in my shell:

```
<QuerySet []>
```

Any idea?

**EDIT : Solution Found**

I found this solution :

```
class LastestListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'records'
    model = models.Record
    ordering = ['-date']
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter(pk__in=
        Record.objects.order_by('-date').values('client__id').annotate(
            max_id=Max('id')).values('max_id'))
```

Comment: You're getting a list of Client IDs, but attempting to use them to filter on the Record id.

Answer (score -1):

<s>Why not `Record.objects.filter(client_id=<client_id>).order_by('-date').last()`?</s>

I see, then the best way may be with a `cached_property`

models.py:

```
class Client(models.model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    ....
    @cached_property
    def latest_record = Record.objects.filter(client=self).order_by('-date').last()
```

Then in your view:

```
clients = Client.objects.all().prefetch_related('record')
```

and

```
for client in clients:
   print(client.name)
   print(client.latest_record.date)
```

This would give you the output you asked for in the question.

Comment: how much records do you get by your solution? OP want all clients

Comment: Hello Rob, Client is not a model. This is a field of Record. To be more precise, this field is a ForeignKey for User.

Comment: It is a model, then. It's a `User` model. I think it would work this way. There are others, though. Perhaps you could get `Record`s and `group_by('client_id')` and `order_by('-date')`. Then do some purging as you loop through the queryset results. I don't think this would be as clean, though.

Comment: Ok Rob, I can try this. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome. if you need more help, I'm happy to. With more details we could come up with a good solution. Not sure why my answer was downvoted, though :\

Comment: The previous answer does not work :( Any proposition is appreciated

Comment: Sure. When you say it didn't work, what exactly do you mean?