# Ordering listview with get_queryset

Tags: django, django-orm

Two models : Post and Author
This view displays the last Post for each Author (author is a ForeignKey)

I want to have these posts in a descending order, but it does not work.
The template keeps displaying these in a ascending way.

I try this following:

**views.py**

```
class LastestListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    model = models.Post
    ordering = ['-date']
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter(pk__in=
        Post.objects.values('author__id').annotate(
            max_id=Max('id')).values('max_id'))
```

or:

```
class LastestListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    model = models.Post
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter(pk__in=
        Post.objects.order_by('-date').values('author__id').annotate(
            max_id=Max('id')).values('max_id'))
```

#### Solution

The ordering has to be set in the beginning of the Queryset:

```
class LastestListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    model = models.Post
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.order_by('-date').filter(pk__in=
        Post.objects.values('author__id').annotate(
            max_id=Max('id')).values('max_id'))
```

Comment: It should be noted that the date of Post is usually increasing by id, which makes it easy. - Do you want to close [your older question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46367796/448474) that seems solved by this also?

Answer (score 5):

It is more exact to say that the **ordering should be applied to the main query**, not to subquery.

I prefer the ordering after a filter, it is only a matter of opinion.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = (
        self.model.objects
        .filter(
            pk__in=(
                Post.objects
                .values('author_id')
                .annotate(max_id=Max('id'))
                .values('max_id')
            )
        )
        .order_by('-date')
    )
    # print(str(qs.query))   # SQL check is perfect for debugging
    return qs
```

Maybe this more sparse style with strict indenting helps to write an easily readable code. The advantage is that you can easier comment out a method or change the order of methods by changing the order of lines. You can see also clearly if `order_by` is in the main query or a subquery.